# After installing material design i am unable to compile the angular code due to ngcc . I attached my error trace down

Tags: angular, angular-material, ng-bootstrap

```
Compiling @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap : module as esm5
Error: Error on worker #1: Error: Failed to compile entry-point @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap (module as esm5) due to compilation errors:
node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/rating/rating.js:148:43 - error NG1006: Cannot combine @Input decorators with query decorators

148         "starTemplate": [{ type: Input }, { type: ContentChild, args: [TemplateRef,] },],
                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/rating/rating.module.js:12:51 - error NG6001: The class 'NgbRating' is listed in the declarations of the
NgModule 'NgbRatingModule', but is not a directive, a component, or a pipe. Either remove it from the NgModule's declarations, or add an appropriate Angular decorator.

12         { type: NgModule, args: [{ declarations: [NgbRating], exports: [NgbRating], imports: [CommonModule] },] },
                                                     ~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/rating/rating.js:14:5
    14 var NgbRating = /** @class */ (function () {
           ~~~~~~~~~
    'NgbRating' is declared here.
node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/rating/rating.js:14:5 - error NG6003: Appears in the NgModule.exports of NgbRatingModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule, Component, Directive, or Pipe class.
```

Is it missing an Angular annotation?

```
14 var NgbRating = /** @class */ (function () {
       ~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/rating/rating.module.js:7:5 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of NgbRootModule, but itself
has errors

7 var NgbRatingModule = /** @class */ (function () {
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/rating/rating.module.js:7:5 - error NG6003: Appears in the NgModule.exports of NgbRootModule, but itself
has errors

7 var NgbRatingModule = /** @class */ (function () {
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/rating/rating.module.js:7:5 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of NgbModule, but itself has
errors

7 var NgbRatingModule = /** @class */ (function () {
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/rating/rating.module.js:7:5 - error NG6003: Appears in the NgModule.exports of NgbModule, but itself has
errors

7 var NgbRatingModule = /** @class */ (function () {
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    at ClusterWorker.compile (C:\Users\adduru.yeswanth\Tool Front End\tools\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\main.js:178:27)
    at Worker.<anonymous> (C:\Users\adduru.yeswanth\Tool Front End\tools\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\execution\cluster\worker.js:44:42)
    at Worker.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at process.Worker.process.on (internal/cluster/worker.js:28:12)
    at process.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at emit (internal/child_process.js:812:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
    at ClusterMaster.onWorkerMessage (C:\Users\adduru.yeswanth\Tool Front End\tools\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\execution\cluster\master.js:165:27)
    at C:\Users\adduru.yeswanth\Tool Front End\tools\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\execution\cluster\master.js:49:95
    at ClusterMaster.<anonymous> (C:\Users\adduru.yeswanth\Tool Front End\tools\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\execution\cluster\master.js:245:57)
    at step (C:\Users\adduru.yeswanth\Tool Front End\tools\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:139:27)
    at Object.next (C:\Users\adduru.yeswanth\Tool Front End\tools\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:120:57)
    at C:\Users\adduru.yeswanth\Tool Front End\tools\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:113:75
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.__awaiter (C:\Users\adduru.yeswanth\Tool Front End\tools\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:109:16)
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\adduru.yeswanth\Tool Front End\tools\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\execution\cluster\master.js:239:32)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
An unhandled exception occurred: NGCC failed.
See "C:\Users\ADDURU~1.YES\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-RAy48O\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow. For getting answer please explain some context about your code.

Comment: What version of Angular, ng-bootstrap and Material are you using?

Comment: @Flix same issue I got when I have installed bootstrap using ng add @ng-bootstrap/schematics command. I am working with angular 9 and its installed bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 7):

`@Iolabs`, yes that's the answer. and worked for me with few more adjustments.

Well I took a similar approach of using `npm install @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`
on the CLI but ran to the same problem. Then I tried to install via npm and still got a similar result.

however, I notice that when I used the ng add again, I got a new error:

> The package that you are trying to add does not support schematics.
>   You can try using a different version of the package or contact the
>   package author to add ng-add support.

I then : npm uninstall @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap

and ran: `ng add  @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`

and package worked like a charm is still not sure how packages broke in the first place.

One more thing: make sure to remove `NgbModule.forRoot()`, if you are using `angular9.x.x`

Comment: this looks more like a discussion than a real answer to the question, isn't it ? Does it really add something new ?

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue while adding bootstrap to an Angular 9 project using the schematics with `ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`.

I ended up adding bootstrap manually like that and is working now.

Install Bootstrap

```
npm install bootstrap
```

Add css or scss files

if you use CSS. add following styles in your `angular.json`:

```
"yourApp": {
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "options": {
        "styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

if you use SCSS, add following import to your `styles.scss`

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Install localize polyfill

```
ng add @angular/localize
```

Install bootstrap

```
npm install @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

Once installed you need to import NgbModule and you're good to go

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
   imports: [NgbModule],
})
export class YourAppModule {
}
```

You can find detailed information here [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started#installation)

To make sure that you have a clean installation, delete your `node_modules` and install them again via `npm install`.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Also had to manually add `import '@angular/localize/init';` to `polyfills.ts`

There were some errors during this step; `ng add @angular/localize`

> An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module
>   '@angular-devkit/core' Require stack:....